# cassandra cannot select more than 500000 records by CQL command

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have to store and access up to 5 million records in Cassandra table using CQL but Cassandra is being terminated when record exceeded from 500000 records picture is attached.... please guide me, what should I do?

I have used query `select * from log_table limit 600000;`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not a Cassandra/CQL problem, but a limitation of the `cqlsh` client which limits the number of returned rows.